# Directly destructor call of class type

Tags: c++, class, destructor, language-lawyer

The code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A
{
    class D{ };
    class C
    {
    public:
        static const int a=7;
        ~C(){ std::cout << "Destroyed"; }
        C() { std::cout << "Created"; }
    };
}

int main()
{
    typedef A::C zlp;
    zlp *z= new zlp();
    z->A::D::~zlp();//error: ‘A::D’ is not a base of ‘zlp {aka A::C}’
}
```

I read the 3.4.3/1 N3797. There is written the

> If a pseudo-destructor-name (5.2.4) contains a nested-name-specifier,
>   the type-names are looked up as types in the scope designated by the
>   nested-name-specifier. Similarly, in a qualified-id of the form:
>
> ```
> nested-name-specifier_opt class-name :: ~ class-name
> ```
>
> the second class-name is looked up in the same scope as the first.

This quote does not say that `nested-name-specifier_opt class-name` must be a base type of `zlp`. Can you explain that behavior? I would like to find a corresponding reference to the standard.

Comment: There is no such quote in the appropriate paragraph

Comment: @Arcoth n3797 3.4.3/6

Comment: clang++ says *error: expected the class name after '~' to name a destructor* I would have guessed that the name `zlp` is looked up in the scope of `A` (the same scope `D` is looked up in).

Comment: @BenVoigt D'oh .. that happens all the time :( http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#244

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can attempt to parse the construct

```
z->A::D::~zlp
```

as either "*postfix-expression* `->` `template`<sub>opt</sub> *id-expression*" (an ordinary member access expression) or as "*postfix-expression* `->` *pseudo-destructor-name*" (see grammar at [expr.post]/1 of N3797).

[expr.pseudo]/1, on pseudo destructor calls, only permits the left operand to be of scalar type. Evidently, `z->A::D::~zlp()` is not a valid pseudo destructor call.

The intent of the standard was that the first grammar production is applicable when the left operand is of class type (since the second one, requiring a scalar type, would obviously be ill formed). The syntactic ambiguity was removed in C++20. This isn't directly relevant to this question, so I won't discuss it further.

Going back to N3797, the question is whether we can interpret `z->A::D::~zlp` as a valid member access expression of the form "*postfix-expression* `->` `template`<sub>opt</sub> *id-expression*". It really boils down to whether `A::D::~zlp` is a valid *id-expression*. [expr.prim.general] governs *id-expressions*, and paragraph 9 in particular concerns *qualified-id*s where the *nested-name-specifier* names a class:

> A *nested-name-specifier* that denotes a class, optionally followed by the keyword `template` (14.2), and then
> followed by the name of a member of either that class (9.2) or one of its base classes (Clause 10), is a
> *qualified-id*; 3.4.3.1 describes name lookup for class members that appear in *qualified-ids*. The result is the
> member. The type of the result is the type of the member. The result is an lvalue if the member is a static
> member function or a data member and a prvalue otherwise. [*Note:* ...] Where *class-name* `::` `~` *class-name* is used, the two class-names shall refer to the same class; this notation names the destructor (12.4). [...]

Because `~zlp` isn't a member of `A::D` nor a member of a base class of `A::D` (indeed, `A::D` has no base classes), `A::D::~zlp` is not even a valid *qualified-id*. Even if it were a *qualified-id*, it would still be ill-formed because of the special rule about naming destructors, where the types must match exactly; you cannot name a base class destructor using a *nested-name-specifier* denoting a derived class.